# Docker creating a new image with an added Java application

Tags: java, docker

Say I would like to distributed a Docker image on top of the dockerfile/java (from DockerHub) which contains an executable Jar file that is sitting in my local box. How would I do that?

> bash-3.2$ pwd
>   /Users/czou/workspace/echodocker
>
> bash-3.2$ cat Dockerfile
>
> FROM dockerfile/java:latest
>
> MAINTAINER X Y
>
> ADD ../testing/echoservice-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/ /data/echoservice
>
> EXPOSE 8080
>
> EXPOSE 8081
>
> bash-3.2$ ls ../testing/echoservice-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/
>
> bin   config  lib

We I run 'docker build .', it always give me:

../testing/echoservice-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/: no such file or directory

The documentation calls for context of the build, what does it really mean? I found it to be very confusing .....

Answer (score 1):

> Structure of java aplication

```
Demo
└── src
|    ├── main
|    │   ├── java
|    │   │   └── org
|    │   │       └── demo
|    │   │           └── .java
|    │   └── resources
|    │       └── application.properties
|    └── test
|         └── java
|               └── org
|                   └── demo
|                         └── App.java  
├──── Dockerfile
├──── pom.xml
```

> Content of Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/demo.jar demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo.jar"]
```

> Commands to build and run image
>
> - Go to the directory of project.Lets say D:/Demo

```
$ cd D/demo
$ mvn clean install
$ docker build demo .
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -t demo
```

> Check that container is running or not

```
$ docker ps
```

> The output will be

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
55c11a464f5a        demo1               "java -jar demo.jar"   21 seconds ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   cranky_mayer
```

> Find video at [Spring Boot with Docker](https://youtu.be/Ojs9I-gnkc8)

Answer (score 0):

The context of the build in your case is the `echodocker` directory, where your `Dockerfile` is located. The contents of the context directory are transferred to the Docker daemon (different from the `docker` command running on your terminal), which is what actually executes the build commands. This means it can only access what's in the context directory. In this case, you are trying to add something outside of the context directory, which is *not* transferred to the Docker daemon. So, that won't work.

To resolve this, you could put your `Dockerfile` in the `echoservice-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` directory (it would then be part of your context). Alternatively, you could symlink `echoservice-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` into your `echodocker` directory, which would cause it to be transferred to the daemon as part of the context directory there.